# ASP.NET disable double click

Tags: asp.net

I have a page where the user can enter data and on submit, it shows up on a gridview right below it.

How do I prevent double click. I understand I can disable the button but that would defeat the purpose as then, the user cannot enter more information without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always disable the button and then use setTimeout to re-enable the button after second or two: http://jsfiddle.net/BJKy4/

```
$("#btn").click(function () {
   var button = $(this);
    button.prop('disabled', true);
    setTimeout(function () {
        button.prop('disabled', false);
    }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I add a class to all elements I dont want the ability to add a double click

```
$('.disableDoubleClick').dblclick(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

this question has been answered many times, just google disabling double clicking in asp.net